# Nested tabs views are not binding to separate ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, tabbedpage

i want to bind viewmodel to nested tab views in xamarin prism framework

i created 4 main pages(A,B,C,D) as main tabs and inside first tab(A) i created two more tabs(A1,A2).but data for nested tabs are not binding.even viewmodel for that views(A1,A2) are not hitting

MenuPage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.MenuPage"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Prism.Behaviors;assembly=Prism.Forms"

             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" 
              xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"

                BarBackgroundColor="White"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <views:A Title="A" Icon="abc.png" />
        <views:B Title="B" Icon="abc.png" />
        <views:C Title="C" Icon="abc.png" />
        <views:D Title="D" Icon="abc.png"/>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

and my page A is like

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.A">
    <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <TabbedPage.Children>
    <views:A1 Title="A1" />
    <views:A2 Title="A2" />

        </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

and i have separate viewmodel for A1 and A2.

so if i directly bind A1 to main navigation page it will work properly and render data.but if i do like above viewmodel for A1 is not hitting the constructor and nothing is displaying apart from static data.i am new to tabbed page navigation.any help is appreciated.this the view i am trying t achieve[image]

Comment: What kind of requirement do you have? Why do you need to nest TabbedPages!?

Comment: @G.hakim i added the image to my question what  i am trying to achieve..

Comment: I do not think these are nested tab views

Comment: @ G.hakim do you have any suggestion for how to acheive this

Comment: u can create those above stuff in grid and can add contentview to grid on click

Comment: @ Ronak Shethia i am stuck with creating tabs inside tabs.which is the proper way.any example or code snippet which using prism will be helpful.thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find we should add `AutowireViewModel` in the page's XAML to load the view model we want:

```
xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
```

Generally, we use `containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<>();` to bind the custom view model to a certain view. But you placed a sub tabbed page in the root tabbed page. This caused the nested view losing the mapping to the corresponding view model. After adding the `AutowireViewModel`, this issue fixed. We could still use `RegisterForNavigation` to bind your custom view model to your special view instead of the automatic naming conversation.

Here is my sample for a simple nested tabbed page: https://github.com/landl0526/PrismTabDemo. Refer to it for more detailed code.

Moreover, this only works on the Android platform as iOS only has the bottom aligned tabbar.

Comment: thanks for your reply and sample code. this is what i was looking for.only one thing how to bring  active nav bar on top.I tried``` <TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="MenuItem1" Order="Primary" Icon="ic_notifications_active_white.png" Text="Item 1" Priority="0" />
    </TabbedPage.ToolbarItems>``` but not working

Comment: @ebk What do you mean "nav bar on top"? Which tabbed page are you manipulating?

Comment: @ Land Lu - MSFT as you can see the image i kept on top,i need a section for showing a logo which should be for the first maintab.and nav bar on top means for keeping toolbar item which is common to all maintabs.like main navi in your subtabpage2 example.

Comment: @ebk If your original has been fixed. You could open a new thread, specify your requirements there. We could talk about it there. And if you felt this is helpful for you, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: defanitelty i will make this answer as acceptable.for you its just a matter of time.please help me

Comment: @ebk What I mean above is recommending you to open a new thread due to one thread for one question. I will post my answer if I find some workaround for your new issues. I need more information about the image and top navi.